# MongoDB query is JSONArray instead JSONObject

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to select a whole document and send it as JSONObject.

```js
app.post('/getinvbykost', function(request, response){ 
    var tablename = request.body.tablename; 
    Move.find({tablename: tablename}, function(err, doc) {
        response.json(doc);
    }); 
});
```

This gives the correct result but with "[]" ->Array and not with {} ->JSONObject. btw: I got the same issue with `Move.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, res) {...`

result:

```
[
  {
    STUFF  
  }
]
```

There is a function $unwind but I dont get it....

Comment: So.... respond with just the first one. `doc[0]` Or, use the `findOne` method.

Comment: Please note, there's no such thing as a JSONArray or a JSONObject, only JSON, Objects, and Arrays. `doc` is an array, and express converts it to JSON when sending it to the client using the `res.json` method.

Comment: Well, that's because `#find` returns an _array_ of documents. If you need your results to be an Object with each property corresponding to some identifying data, use [_.indexBy](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy) or similar code of your own.

Comment: findOne solved it, so easy ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case since you only want one result, the **findOne** method would be more appropriate.

```
app.post('/getinvbykost', function(request, response){ 
    var tablename = request.body.tablename; 
    Move.findOne({tablename: tablename}, function(err, doc) {
        response.json(doc);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yes, that was my comment. :)

Comment: I need to put a WHERE clause in it. It is right that findOne doesnt accept a WHERE-clause?

Comment: the tablename: tablename is a where clause. but, yes, you can remove the callback and instead use .where and .exec

Comment: blind in the morning, of course, thank you `Model.findOne({tablename: tablename, accepted : false}, function(err, res) {}`

Comment: The result is a JSONObject. Why i cant push another value to it?

Comment: with `res.push({"success": true});` or `res["success"] = "true";`

Comment: push definitely won't work, but the other should. Try using .toObject() on it and storing that in a temp var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84240/discussion-between-piet-and-kevin-b).